# Django - Creating data with or without .create()

Tags: django

I'm following the official Django Tutorial and confused about this part:

Sometimes they create a model data without `.create()` like:

```
Poll(pub_date= timezone.now() )
```

and sometimes they use `.create()` like:

```
Poll.objects.create(pub_date= timezone.now() )
```

From what I run, both returns the same result. So is there any difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latter saves it in the table (performs an implicit `.save()`). The former does not.